# Jenkins with Fastlane cocoapods action unable to detect podfile

Tags: ios, jenkins, cocoapods, fastlane

I have successfully setup Jenkins server on a macmini. I use the port 8081 for launching Jenkins. An iOS Application project of mine needs automated builds to be archived. I have used fastlane with swift for this purpose. The iOS project also has dependencies on cocoapods. The Podfile is in the root folder of the project.

In the fastfile before doing a buildApp action I do a cocoapods action. The fastfile is in fastlane folder, which is located at the root folder of the iOS project. The cocoapods action call in the fastfile is as below

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let path = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
cocoapods(
    clean: true,
    //Probable issue with cocoapods() action in fastlane from jenkins
    //1. For first time build we need ./Podfile path
    //podfile: "./Podfile"
    //2. For later builds we need path to be absolutepath/Podfile
    podfile: "\(path)/Podfile"
)
```

The problem I am facing is a curious one.

When I do a build for the first time in the life time of Jenkins project, I need to have the pod file path as ***"./Podfile"*** as in 1 of the commented code. 
For other subsequent builds, this path is invalid for cocoapods action as it logs error that it cannot find the Poddfile.

I tried changing the podfile path to give it absolute path as in 2 in the above code. To my surprise it worked well and my subsequent builds were successful.

I think this behaviour is unexpected. I want to know if I am doing something wrong here or is it fastlane/jenkins path resolving bug?

Comment: Can you provide more information? From what directory are you calling `fastlane`? Is your call to `cocoapods` in a lane, or in a `before_all`? How did you install `fastlane`? Is it possible that the code that is running before the call is changing the current working directory if the `Fastfile` has already been run once?

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson I have an Xcode project. The Xcode projects Root directory has a fastlane folder. Inside the fastlane folder lies the fastfile. There I have implemented a lane which does the following actions: 1. Delete existing custom key chain created by me for storing certficates.  2. createKeychain 3. importCerticate. 4. cocoapods. 5. updateProjectProvisioning 6. buildApp

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson do any of the actions from 2 to 5 change the current working directory. The action 1 is written by and is simple usage of the default file manager to delete the keychain file.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if any of those fastlane actions change the working directory *if* I understand the problem correctly. From what I understand, the first time you run `fastlane mylane` the path for the Podfile has to be `./Podfile`. The second time you run it, the path for the Podfile has to be `./somethingelse/Podfile` for this code to run without an issue. That tells me that the current working directory the second time you run it (from the Terminal/Command-Line), is different ==> that would explain the problem.

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson thanks for giving me this perspective. I will look into if any actions is changing the working directory.